In-Text Footnotes Immediately Following an R-Ball or Service Mark
Can I immediately follow a registered/trade/service mark with a footnote number?
For example: ... our Analysis Business Checking(R)1,2,3 account.?
If yes, would a comma follow the R-ball?
